# Manipulating elements of list and populating a new list with elements of old list

Tags: list-manipulation

Suppose I have the list

```
peakwavelengths = {769, 717, 672, 631, 597, 565, 537, 513, 491, 471, 454, 438, 424, \
411, 399, 390, 381, 374, 351, 346, 342, 339, 337, 332, 328, 324, 321, \
318, 314, 310, 303, 296, 288, 280, 277, 275, 273, 269, 265, 261, 255, \
248, 244, 238, 236, 234, 223};
nGaN[\[Lambda]_] := (3.60 + (
   1.75 (\[Lambda]/1000)^2)/((\[Lambda]/1000)^2 - 0.256^2) + (
   4.1 (\[Lambda]/1000)^2)/((\[Lambda]/1000)^2 - 17.86^2))^0.5
thickness[\[Lambda]1_, \[Lambda]2_] := (\[Lambda]1*\[Lambda]2)/(
 2 (\[Lambda]1*nGaN[\[Lambda]2] - \[Lambda]2*nGaN[\[Lambda]1]))
```

Now I want to make a new list with thickness[[Lambda]1_, [Lambda]2_] as elements of the list where the $\lambda_1$ and $\lambda_2$ are consecutive elements of peakwavelengths list.

Comment: `Map[thickness@@#&,Partition[peakwavelengths,2]]` if you don't want consecutive elements to overlap and `Map[thickness@@#&,Partition[peakwavelengths,2,1]]` if you do want them to overlap. Look up `@@` in the help system to see how that is putting a list of two elements into your `thickness` function that doesn't accept a list. And `#` and `&` are part of `Function`

Comment: What do you mean by overlap and not overlap?

Comment: Thanks a lot Bill.

Comment: Thank you. Do you have any links for how should I define a new list suppose I have to manipulate say $i$, $i+2$, $i+6$ etc. random elements of the list?

Comment: I understand, but I don't know the syntax of how to access the elements of the list as in I can access 1st,2nd, 3rd elements etc. but how to access an indexed element such as $i$ element?

Comment: Yes that's what I wanted. Thanks again. I did not know the Table function.

Comment: I do not know where you live, that will change this advice. Go to http://allbookstores.com and search for "Mathematica Navigator" and look at some of the older editions. Here in U.S. I can buy a copy of that delivered for less than $6. I urge anyone to buy a copy and read all that as fast as you can go. That will help you in many ways. The latest edition is not needed to show you many of the things you need to help make Mathematica easier to use.